# Nginx server is stopping for no apparent reason

Tags: php, mysql, nginx

I've set up an Nginx server for my site. Unfortunately, Nginx stops after some days (it's not a fixed period, sometimes after 5 days, sometimes after 1 month) and my site goes down. I need to restart it every time.

Can anybody tell me why this is happening?

I've checked the error log (`var/log/nginx/error.log`) and I can't see any specific information that is making the server go down. I've also looked through `syslog` and `access.log` to check if there is anything that causes the server to stop, but haven't had any luck.

My website is otherwise working perfectly. I've also checked the PHP and mysql error logs, but there is nothing showing up that is making the server stop.

Any help is appreciated. Please let me know if any other information is required.

Latest errors in `error.log`: replaced domain name with `example.com`

```
2018/07/30 11:25:40 [error] 35769#0: *1047 access forbidden by rule, client: 79.199.227.124, server: knxtool.com, request: "GET /phpmyadmin/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com", referrer: "example.com/phpmyadmin/index.php?db=virginswedish_58d532a2bec2f&token=4c7ee221dd5767cd6bf8edf00e737084"
2018/07/30 11:25:40 [error] 35769#0: *1047 access forbidden by rule, client: 79.199.227.124, server: example.com, request: "GET /phpmyadmin/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/phpmyadmin/index.php?db=virginswedish_58d532a2bec2f&token=4c7ee221dd5767cd6bf8edf00e737084"
2018/07/30 13:20:43 [alert] 35765#0: worker process 35766 exited on signal 9
2018/07/30 13:20:43 [alert] 35765#0: worker process 35769 exited on signal 9
2018/07/30 13:25:00 [alert] 41155#0: worker process 41156 exited on signal 9
2018/07/30 13:25:00 [alert] 41155#0: worker process 41157 exited on signal 9
```

Comment: did you check `dmesg` for OOM-type messages?

Comment: I don't know what is that. Can you tell me more information?

Comment: Please still attach the latest parts of nginx's error log, even if you don't believe there is anything relevant.

Comment: [`dmesg`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dmesg) or [OOM (Out of Memory)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_memory)?

Comment: @Fanatique. Error messages added

Comment: @Attie. Thanks I will look into that and let you know

Comment: Signal 9 is `SIGKILL`... so something has killed off your workers. The OOM killer sends `SIGKILL` when it has to free up memory - please check `dmesg`

Comment: @Attie. Thanks. I will run dmesg command and let you know the response. Does the error message shows something regarding memory issue?

Comment: @Attie. I have run `dmesg` command, Do you want me to check anything in that? Is my server going down because of memory allocation?

Comment: Please run something like `dmesg | grep -iC3 "out of memory"` and update your question with the output. You could get a feel for how loaded your server is by watching the memory usage in `htop` or similar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80913/discussion-between-sudharshan-nair-and-attie).

Comment: @Attie. I just ran tmux now and are you sure it will log errors when server goes down, Because I opened it and I didn't find anything inside it till now, So just to confirm